# Duda de Relaciones en Eloquent con Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy tratando de hacer mi login personalizado en Laravel. Actualmente tengo las siguientes tablas:

- Users.
- Employees.

Users: rut email

Employee: rut password

Ellas tienen una relación de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  use Notifiable;

  public function employee()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'rut');
  }
}
```

En el formulario de Login yo lo apunto hacia un controlador que se llama EnterController quedando de esta forma:

```
<?php
class EnterController extends Controller
{

  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)
        ->count();
  }
}
```

Mi duda es como pueden ver en el controlador estoy haciendo una consulta a User con el correo pero en esa misma consulta necesito agregar employee, como pueden ver tienen un relación arriba en el modelo de User. ¿Cómo tendría que ser la consulta para que el WHERE busque email en la tabla USER y el password en la tabla Employee siendo que ellas estan relacionadas en el modelo?

PD: Solo eloquent.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y por qué debe buscar en 2 tablas distintas?, ¿no debería solo buscar en la tabla de users?, es que no le veo sentido a esto que propones

Comment: Apoyo a  @BetaM tu mismo te enredas y te complicas ya que el login deberias de hacerlo solo en una tabla, puedes cambiar la tabla de donde haces login pero no estoy seguro de que tan bueno sea intentarlo con dos tablas

Comment: @BetaM es que no lo puedo hacer en la tabla de User por la logica del negocio por eso es.

Comment: Te invitaría a que repiensen esa lógica por que por ejemplo, ¿por qué la contraseña en el empleado, cuando tendría mas sentido que sea un atributo del user?